Gmsh install issue on anaconda
I noticed the gmsh release on Anaconda is 4.11.1 wherease the latest on the conda forge is 4.13.0 (conda forge link.
I uninstalled it, cleaned conda cache, disabled channel-priority, etc. but whatever i do, it's always the 4.11.1 release that is installled, not the newest one: what am i missing?
Thanks
Paul

You can pin the channel and the version in the command line using:
conda install conda-forge::gmsh==4.13.0

